# Text on a path's Selection handles do not show in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, text-on-path

I added text to an ellipse path --but the selection handles (as seen circled in red on the attached graphic example) are not showing.

With the Direct Selection arrow tool selected I can see the text is wrapped ON the path. But no way to adjust or move the text on the path after it's added. See the Del d'Oro ecreen shot.

What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had inadvertently hidden it.

Contrl H unhides it